# How can I create real-time audio effects on PC?

Tags: audio-recording, processing, real-time

Does anyone know how I can create an echo effect in real-time while singing on PC. Lets say I want to sing to an audience over IM and I want an echo/delay effect while I sing. Is there any software available?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 7. I am looking for something like a sound mixer but i need to do it in real time

Answer (score 1):

You could use vst plugins. You will need a host such as [VSTHost](http://www.hermannseib.com/english/vsthost.htm) and a plugin such as [eTAP2](http://www.echotapper.nl/etap2/). You can also get mixer plugins.

[KVRAudio](http://www.kvraudio.com) is good website for finding audio software.

Comment: And ASIO drivers for low-latency sound card access, either provided by the sound card vendor (rare) or Asio4All: http://tippach.business.t-online.de/asio4all/

Comment: how do I have to configure VST Devices (input/output) so that the effects are applied to line-in? considering the latency thing

Answer (score 0):

http://www.audiomulch.com is a simple tool where you can build your setup. It has elements that you can select to build it and among them you have Inputs and Outputs.